# DATEPART from Access via SSIS only partially functional

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I'm using SSIS in Visual Studio to work with an Access diatabase via Execute SQL task. The Access DB has a date field (named FullDate) in Date datatype in the format 20/08/2015 and I have successfully extracted parts of this data (year, month and quarter) into new columns via the following commands:

```
UPDATE DimDate
SET MonthNumber = DATEPART("m", FullDate )

UPDATE DimDate
SET Yr = DATEPART("yyyy", FullDate )

UPDATE DimDate
SET Quart = DATEPART("q", FullDate )
```

However I have been unable to extract the weeknumber or Iso week number, day of year or even day of week with the following:

```
UPDATE DimDate
SET WeekNumber = DATEPART("wk", FullDate )

UPDATE DimDate
SET WeekNumber = DATEPART("isowk", FullDate )

UPDATE DimDate
SET DayNumber = DATEPART("dy", FullDate )

UPDATE DimDate
SET WeekdayNumber = DATEPART("dw", FullDate )
```

The fields into which this data is copied are all byte integers and short integers for the day of year but the SQL task fails.

I've had a long fiddle with this but can't see what the problem is as the Control Flow task just displays a red cross with no other details on the nature of the failure. I have also tried restricting the command to a specific row with a WHERE filter in case an anomalous row was causing the failure but it still fails with seemingly good data and string literal dates.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.
Kw

Comment: So what's the Error message?

Comment: None that I can see. The task just fails with a red cross icon instead of the usual green tick for success. I have looked in the Errors panel but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Results pane will have Error information. Also, Output window will contain the text

Comment: I'm no expert, but none of the date part constants you're having a problem with are the [right ones for Access, as far as I can see in the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa)...

Comment: Matt Gibson has it right.  The constants you're using are for T-SQL DATEPART.  Access speaks a slightly different dialect of SQL.

Comment: Thanks billinkc, very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Matt Gibson and SebTHU, that did the trick.